# How to SELECT oracle LONG column datatype to MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I want to SELECT data from oracle database table to MVC views in visual studio , every thing work fine except one field its datatype LONG , this is the code i use :

```
public ActionResult Radiology()

{
    string sql = @"SELECT a.rad_order_no , 
                          serv_request_date , 
                          approving_date ,
                          d.LONG_FORIEGN_DESC , 
                          report_result 
                  FROM RAD_ORDER_HEADER a , RAD_IMAGE_HEADER b ,RAD_REPORT_RESULT  c,HOSPITAL_SERVICES d 
                  WHERE a.HOSPITAL_NO = b.HOSPITAL_NO
                  AND a.HOSPITAL_NO = c.HOSPITAL_NO
                  AND b.HOSPITAL_NO = c.HOSPITAL_NO
                  AND A.HOSPITAL_NO=d.HOSPITAL_NO
                  AND b.HOSPITAL_NO=d.HOSPITAL_NO
                  AND d.DEPT_NO=6
                  AND c.SERV_NO=d.SERV_NO
                  AND a.RAD_ORDER_NO = b.RAD_ORDER_NO
                  AND b.IMAGE_NO = c.IMAGE_NO
                  AND b.SERV_NO = c.SERV_NO  ";

    string condition = "";
    condition += " AND a.PATIENT_NO = '" + Session["MRN"] + "'";


    DataTable dt = func.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql+condition));
    return View(dt);
}
```

[image]
And this is cshtml code :

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Radiology";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
}

<h2>Radiology</h2>


<h3>Welcome : @Session["IDNO"].ToString()   :مرحبا </h3>
@*<a href="@Url.Action("Logout","Login")"> Logout </a>*@

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> Order No/رقم الطلب </th>
        <th> Date Of Request/تاريخ الطلب  </th>
        <th> Report Date/تاريخ النتيجة    </th>
        <th> Service/اسم الخدمة</th>
        <th> Report Result/تقرير النتيجة </th>



    </tr>

    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in Model.Rows)
    {

    <tr>
        <td>@dr["rad_order_no"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["serv_request_date"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["approving_date"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["LONG_FORIEGN_DESC"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["report_result"].ToString()</td>

    </tr>

    }

</table>
```

The field is report result its not show the report , how to view the report and deal with LONG column data type with MVC and get the data to my views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from oracle side SQL side : 
LONG datatype can save up to 32000 character and varchar2 can save up to 4000 character and ASP.NET MVC can view VARCHAR datatype columns , so the solution was convert LONG datatype to VARCHAR by using the following function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_long(r ROWID) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
temporary_varchar VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
SELECT REPORT_RESULT INTO temporary_varchar FROM RAD_REPORT_RESULT WHERE ROWID=r;
RETURN temporary_varchar;
END;
/
```

then I called the function in SQL SELECT :

```
string sql = @"SELECT a.rad_order_no , 
                                  serv_request_date , 
                                  approving_date ,
                                  d.LONG_FORIEGN_DESC , 
                                  SEARCH_LONG(C.ROWID) 
                          FROM RAD_ORDER_HEADER a , RAD_IMAGE_HEADER b ,RAD_REPORT_RESULT  c,HOSPITAL_SERVICES d 
                          WHERE a.HOSPITAL_NO = b.HOSPITAL_NO
                          AND a.HOSPITAL_NO = c.HOSPITAL_NO
                          AND b.HOSPITAL_NO = c.HOSPITAL_NO
                          AND A.HOSPITAL_NO=d.HOSPITAL_NO
                          AND b.HOSPITAL_NO=d.HOSPITAL_NO
                          AND d.DEPT_NO=6
                          AND c.SERV_NO=d.SERV_NO
                          AND a.RAD_ORDER_NO = b.RAD_ORDER_NO
                          AND b.IMAGE_NO = c.IMAGE_NO
                          AND b.SERV_NO = c.SERV_NO  ";
```

Finally in the view Radiology.cshtml foreach loop i used that column also SEARCH_LONG(C.ROWID)  instead of report_result

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in Model.Rows)
    {

    <tr>
        <td>@dr["rad_order_no"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["serv_request_date"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["approving_date"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["LONG_FORIEGN_DESC"].ToString()</td>
        <td>@dr["SEARCH_LONG(C.ROWID)"].ToString()</td>

    </tr>
```

and the output ok now

Answer (score 0):

Try [TO_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions185.htm) with the long column and check if MVC has CLOB type